# How to queue multiple tasks on one separate thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to create a only one new Thread and queue up all work in that single thread. The only way I know how to do it would be this way:

```
Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(job1));
```

but that is creating a new thread everytime.

Edit:

Here is more code:

```
client.MessageReceived.Subscribe(async info =>
        {
            try
            {
                var response = APICALL();
                if (response.Id == "2345")
                    return;

                var bal = response.bal;
                bal.InsertToDB();
                if (bal.Acct != null)
                {
                    var acct = GETACCT();
                    foreach(var ac in acct){
                       if (bal.mul != ac.mul)
                       {
                           updateACC(bal, ac);                               
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logging.LogException(e);
            }
        });
```

I want to put the updateACC(bal, ac); in a thread. There are messages coming frequently from the websocket and on top of that there's the foreach loop for every account. Doing `new Thread()` for updateAcc() would be wasteful. So is there a way to name a thread and just add updateACC() to that named thread?

Comment: You most likely shouldn't be working with threads at all. You should let the threadpool manage the work. Why do you think you need a single thread?

Comment: the code i want to add to the thread is in a loop, i dont want to end up creating 100s of `new Thread()`.

Comment: @FahadJameel - Put the loop inside of job1.

Comment: Can you show more code and explain what you're functionally trying to accomplish?  Is this a long running process that is doing work and needs to always be running, or just a one time process being kicked off as fire and forget?  Is there a loop or something?  There's no code there that shows multiple threads being created.

Comment: Consider using a [thread safe collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/), specifically a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` to submit work to your thread and let the thread consume this queue.

Comment: I updated my code to give more context.

Comment: Take a look at the .NET Task Parallel Library (TPL) if under Windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl

Comment: You can use async/await instead of trying to manage threads.  If you make your updateACC return a task, you can do an await Task.WhenAll(acct.Where(ac => bal.mul != ac.mul).Select(updateACC(bal, ac))).  A note on WhenAll - we have run into issues using up connections if the number of tasks is too high when making sql calls.  So we made a WhenAllBatchedAsync that loops over the items in batches.  https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: Another option would be to implement a BackgroundService (long running IHostedService) that processes these tasks.  Receive message could add them to a queue (in memory thread safe concurrent queue, SQS, etc.),  and then it could pull them from the queue.  It seems that would be similar to what you are looking for in a "thread that always does the updateACC jobs".  This could introduce a delay in processing though so I'm not sure what's acceptable for your scenario.  Is that approach more the direction you're looking for?

Comment: Is this the same question with the [How to reuse a thread in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74158043/how-to-reuse-a-thread-in-c-sharp)?