# How to reuse a thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I wanted to know how to reuse a thread. I have a websocket connection that constantly sends messages which need some computation to be done. I want to add this computation to a thread, but don't want to create a new thread everytime. How can I make it so that the thread is reused?

```
client.MsgRecieved.Subscribe(info =>
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => Do_work(info));
};
```

Is there a way I can create a thread, name it and then just add `Do_work()` on that thread?

Edit:

I get multiple messages from the websocket per second. I rather have them wait in a single queue, rather than all run on a new thread.

Comment: You can't reuse a thread. Consider using the [ThreadPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=net-6.0).

Comment: I get multiple messages from the websocket per second. I rather have them wait in a single queue, rather than all run on a new thread.

Comment: Then you can use the [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-7.0) (thread safe version of [`Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-6.0)) class for that. Have your one thread constantly loop and try to pull stuff from the queue while another thread adds stuff to it as needed.

Comment: `semaphoreslim`

Comment: What you are asking implies that the `Do_work` will be serialized. Have you considered that in case the `Subscribe` handler is invoked more frequently than the average duration of the `Do_work`, the `info` messages are going to get stacked in an ever increasing buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest pattern is simply

```
client.MsgRecieved.Subscribe(async info =>{
   await Task.Run(Do_work(info));
});
```

Which queues the method to run on the built-in threadpool.

If you want to queue the messages to run on a single background thread, you can use a BlockingCollection, something like:

```
var workQueue = new System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<Object>();
var workThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
{
    foreach (var work in workQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        Do_Work(work);
    }
});

workThread.Start();
```

then

```
client.MsgRecieved.Subscribe(info => {
    workQueue.Add(info);
};
```

Comment: Keep in mind tasks do not directly correlate to threads (multiple tasks can run on the same thread). This also has the potential to throw an error if the task runs for multiple hours and you don't use the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` flag.

Comment: Instead of `client.MsgRecieved.Subscribe(info => { Task.Run(` I would prefer `client.MsgRecieved.Subscribe(async info => { await Task.Run(`, so that any errors that might happen are exposed (as unhandled exceptions).